# Parse list to other list

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a list in python that looks like so:

```
['GIS_FPC_PP,PERIMETER,MAT,LIGHTS,PARK,SPACES,LAT,LNG\n', '8266.99157657,453.7255798,Paved,1,American Legion,20,40.0188044212,-75.0547647126\n', '20054.5870679,928.20201772,Paved,1,Barnes Foundation Museum, ,39.9610355788,-75.1725011285\n']
```

It has a lot of data that I do not need.  All I need is the last two numbers in each entry.  What would be the best way to traverse this list and put all the data that I need into another list of lists where each pair is its own list?

Comment: Can you show your expected output? and the code that you have tried?

Comment: Why do you have this list in the first place? Is that a CSV file so you might be better off using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)?

Comment: This is a CSV file. How would I get just the data I need doing it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go through the list items and split the items after the first one, and get the last two items from the list and append it to a new List

```
l = ['GIS_FPC_PP,PERIMETER,MAT,LIGHTS,PARK,SPACES,LAT,LNG\n',
     '8266.99157657,453.7255798,Paved,1,American Legion,20,40.0188044212,-75.0547647126\n',
     '20054.5870679,928.20201772,Paved,1,Barnes Foundation Museum, ,39.9610355788,-75.1725011285\n']

newList = []
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    item = l[i]
    tempList = []
    if i != 0:
        itemSplit = item.split(',')
        tempList.append(itemSplit[-2].strip())
        tempList.append(itemSplit[-1].strip())
        newList.append(tuple(tempList))
print newList
```

#### Output

```
[('40.0188044212', '-75.0547647126'), ('39.9610355788', '-75.1725011285')]
```

Comment: @jgritty OP states `What would be the best way to traverse this list and put all the data that I need into another list?`

Comment: @jgritty Although my way may not be the `best` it is still a valid way of putting those specified items in a new list

Comment: Sorry, I did notice my OP was vague. I fixed the question.  I want the output list to be a list of lists with each pair as their own list. Also, would there any way to delete the trailing new line in each longitude number?

Comment: @Albert: The method you're looking for is `strip` (to remove whitespace at either end of a string).

Answer (score 3):

```
[[y.strip() for y in x.split(",")[-2:]] for x in original_list[1:]]
```

That is: for each x in the original list (less the first entry, which looks like a header), take the last 2 items you get after splitting it by commas, and strip each of those 2 items (to remove extra whitespace, like the trailing `\n`).